# How to make undertow create session with specified session id from cookie?

Tags: java, spring, undertow

I have undertow + spring 5 + spring security project.
Spring configured to be STATELESS, so no http session created from spring side.

However, when request (with JSESSIONID cookie) made to the undertow server
it invalidates existing id, and generate new one, and create a session.
So instead of using existing jsessionid it creates a new one. So I never have a corresponding http session in the undertow server.

Do you know how to make it use provided jsessionid (from the cookie) and create a session based on it, instead of generating a new session id?

Thanks.